# PHP & JQuery Adding Dynamic Inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm using Jquery in order to add dynamic inputs on my page. I only want to display one input initially, then more can be added by clicking a button.

This works as expected.

I'm then using PHP in order to catch the `$_POST` values of the inputs and send them to an external script. This also works, however I'm always receiving one extra item in my array, and it's empty.

I think this is because I have a hidden `<div>` field in my HTML, which is shown when a new input is generated?

My code is below;

**HTML**

```
// unnecessary code removed
<div class="after-add-more">
  <button class="add-more" type="button" title="Add"></button>
  <input name="addmore[]" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div class="copy-fields hide">
  <div>
    <button class="remove" type="button" title="Remove"></button>
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //here first get the contents of the div with name class copy-fields and add it to after "after-add-more" div class.
    $(".add-more").click(function() {
        var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
        $(".after-add-more").after(html);
    });
    //here it will remove the current value of the remove button which has been pressed
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// unnecessary code removed
$field_values_array = $_POST['addmore'];
?>
```

Without generating an additional input, I enter `1111111` into the input box and submit. A `print_r($_POST)` produces;

```
[addmore] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1111111
        [1] => 
    )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably better just getting the parent of the element that was clicked and adding your markup after that. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // this function handles the click event
  function addField(parent) {
    // find your template, in this case its the first .after-add-more
    var html = $(".after-add-more").first().clone();
    // reset the value of any inputs
    $('input', html).val('');
    // wire the click handler for the button
    $("button", html).click(function() {
      addField($(this).parent());
    });
    // append it to the parent of the parent, addContainer
    html.appendTo(parent.parent());
  }

  // wire the click handler for the add-more button
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    addField($(this).parent());
  });
  
  // I don't know what the intention of this code is so I'm leaving it alone
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// unnecessary code removed
<div id="addContainer">
  <div class="after-add-more">
    <button class="add-more" type="button" title="Add">Add</button>
    <input name="addmore[]" value="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-fields hide">
  <div>
    <button class="remove" type="button" title="Remove">Remove</button>
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I just updated the example a bit to be a little cleaner and a little more robust. Things worth noting - I added a container for all the add elements and left your remove element there but updated the buttons so you can see whats what.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adam H but the remove button doesn't work? To confirm, I need to show *one* input initially (not two as in your example), then add more when the *add* button is clicked.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek well yeah, lol, nothing in your post mentioned the remove functionality. If you don't want the Remove button then just delete the markup.